# IBM-Watson Sentiment Analysis

Tags: python, ibm-watson, sentiment-analysis

I am using IBM Watson for Sentiment Analysis and I get `Forbidden Error 403`. I contacted the IBM customer support mentioning the error and they asked me to check here.

```py
import sys
import json
from ibm_watson import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1
from ibm_watson.natural_language_understanding_v1 import Features, SentimentOptions
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('API Key')
natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(version='2019-07 12',authenticator=authenticator)
response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(text='This is really Awesome', features = Features(sentiment=SentimentOptions())).get_result()
print(response)
```

The Error received is given below:

```py
ERROR:root:Forbidden Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\filepath\filepath2\filepath3\ibm_cloud_sdk_core\base_service.py", line 229, in send response.status_code, error_message, http_response=response)  
ibm_cloud_sdk_core.api_exception.ApiException: Error: Forbidden, Code: 403
```

Comment: I assume you didn't try with `'API Key'`, but actually have a real API key?

Comment: Thanks, Bart... I have tried with the original API key. As I do not want to reveal the key, I have mentioned it as 'API Key' in the code.

Comment: Yeah, thought so, but since you didn't mention this fact in your question, I wanted to make sure.